# Compass compile on Jenkins CI

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, compass

I have the following execute script on my CI environment

```
cd /var/www/html

php vendor/bin/phpunit app/tests --log-junit /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Closecall/workspace/tests/reports/junit.xml
php vendor/bin/phinx migrate -e development
sudo compass compile
```

SSHing onto the CI and compiling myself works fine, however when the CI executes this on build I get the following error

```
+ sudo compass compile
sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Recording test results
Finished: FAILURE
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sudo` by default tries to open `/dev/tty` for read-write. You might not have `/dev/tty` available on the machine you use to build. The need for `tty` is configured in the `/etc/sudoers` file.

`sudo` has an option -S to read the password from standard input instead of `/dev/tty`. You should be able to compile using `sudo -S`.

> The -S (stdin) option causes sudo to read the password from the standard input instead of the terminal device. The password must be followed by a newline character.

http://linux.die.net/man/8/sudo

Comment: I fixed it by doing something similar, by adding jenkins NOPASSWD record into visudo file. This seems like it should also work though, thanks!